# ActiveMQ version conflict with jre 1.5

Tags: activemq-classic, java

I am using Axway server which runs on jre 1.5 . So it accepts all classed builded below 1.6 . But problem is I read  [THIS LINK](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html)  and I got this line as guide

> Environment:
>       * Java Developer Kit (JDK) 1.4.x or greater for deployment and 1.5.x (Java 5) for compiling/building. As of AMQ 5.5.0 you need JDK 1.6.0 to**

Which says I can use ActiveMQs below version 5.5 for jre 1.5.

when I use ActiveMQ 5.4.3 am getting bad class version error.Please help me.

**This is the line where am getting this error**

```
Object o = Class.forName("org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory", 
                                    true,ConnFactory.class.getClassLoader())
                        .newInstance();
```

Comment: Please supply the full error message as emitted from the VM. Also, are you installing to Windows or Linux and are you installing the pre-built jars or are you building from source?

Comment: 1,I am using Sunsolaries OS.2,am using pre-built jars 3,ClassNotfoundException only am getting at line mentioned.

Comment: What is your classpath set to? Also, please supply the full error message including the stack trace.

Comment: also tell us the output of `java -version` command your server.

Comment: Can you please be more specific, for starters copy the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: What is the class `ConnFactory`? Is it your code?

Comment: Without posting the full stacktrace and error from the JVM, consider your question closed.

Comment: I don't think the stacktrace here would be of any help. It's the class.forName saying that the class is not found; we should understand why... stacktrace here is totally worthless

Comment: @LuigiR.Viggiano yes you are right problem is due to the jar entry in jvm config file about new jars or all jars entry. Thanks for all of your help.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem is due to the jvm config file entry for jar newly added.**

I don't know and I am not responsible and I don't have permission to do any Admin related privileges.

I put the jar in CLASSPATH exactly.So its ok for all the classes to access that.

But problem is in JVM config file I have to put the entry, I mean I have to give name of the jar with CLASSPATH in jvm.config file of axway.Though I put my jar in class path without put entry in jvm.config, it is worthless.Because while jvm get initialized it checks the config file first to add jar with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the jar as a zip file, and then look inside the folder and check inside the  META-INF directory. The MANIFEST.MF file will tell you what version of the jvm the jar was compiled with. I just grabbed the 5.4.3 version of the activemq jar and it said this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: chirino
**Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_26**
Specification-Title: ActiveMQ :: Jar Bundle
Specification-Version: 5.4.3
Specification-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: ActiveMQ :: Jar Bundle
Implementation-Version: 5.4.3
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache.activemq
Implementation-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
```

which clearly shows that it was built with the 1.6 jvm. Might need to download the source and build it on 1.5 manually.

Answer (score 1):

In maven repository the last version of activemq built on jdk 1.5 is 5.4.2.